# Yarn - How to set Yarn to use cookies

Tags: node.js, proxy, yarnpkg

I'm using Yarn behind a corporate proxy.

I can successuflly install some packages. But, for some reason, some of then doesn't install and I get the following message in my log:

```
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/napi-build-utils/-/napi-build-utils-1.0.1.tgz: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop in <coporate-address>
```

I had this type of "maxRedirects" error before in other situations and I know that this happens when the use of cookies in the requests is disabled.

For example, in NodeJS when I have to use the "requests" module I need to set the `cafile`, `proxy` and `jar` (it must be set to "true", otherwise I get a "max redirects" error) properties to be able to successfully make HTTPS requests.

Is this possible to do with yarn?

Comment: Thanks @CodyＧ but I already set these properties to fix another issue with my proxy.